# How to run a Python script in VSCode using the same path of the script? (otherwise it can't find an input file located in the same folder)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have this Python code: https://github.com/andreagrandi/aoc_2019/tree/master/aoc
which runs perfectly from the terminal (Python 3 required) if I do for example: `python aoc_03.py`

But if I try to run it from VSCode, taking advantage of the Python extension and integration, I get this error:

```
(aoc) ➜  advent_of_code_2019 git:(master) /Users/andrea/.virtualenvs/aoc/bin/python /Users/andrea/Documents/advent_of_code_2019/aoc/aoc_03.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andrea/Documents/advent_of_code_2019/aoc/aoc_03.py", line 70, in <module>
    with open('aoc_03_input.txt', 'r') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aoc_03_input.txt'
```

My guess is that when invoked from VSCode, the script is run from a different path, so it cannot find the file `aoc_03_input.txt` which is located in the same folder of the script.

How do I tell VSCode to run my script from the `/Users/andrea/Documents/advent_of_code_2019/aoc/` folder, so that it will be able to find my input file?

Thanks

Comment: Open the Terminal, navigate to the location (`cd /Users/andrea/Documents/advent_of_code_2019/aoc/`) and run it from there.

Comment: @ilja Hi, did you actually read the very first 2 lines? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I should have tried more before asking this question, because I just found the solution, but at this point I will write it here in case it can be useful to anyone:

If I change the path in this way:

```
with open('./aoc_03_input.txt', 'r') as file:
```

The file is being open correctly when I run the code in VSCode and when I run it from the terminal. Tested under OSX (but it should work under Linux too. Not sure about Windows).

Comment: I feel dumb. Yesterday it was working correctly. Today is nor working anymore :/